# How can I create an enclosure that will protect an indoor camera outdoors?

Tags: outdoor

My DropCam is an indoor camera and there's no outdoor version, so I would like to come up a way to have this camera outdoors.

So far I thought about creating a casing using:

1. an empty 2 liter soda bottle
2. [Dry Silica Gel](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00B77NFU2)
3. [Silicone Caulk](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000BD0QAK)

As you can see, this casing might work in keeping the camera dry, but I still don't know how to weatherproof the power cord. Does this sound doable? Figured I'd ask here in case anyone has ever been able to make a weatherproof case.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is not rated for outdoors it will fail eventually. All professional outdoor camera housings have vents to allow them to breathe. It is a fact that moisture is going to get to your camera no matter what you build and since it is not rated to handle it it will fail. If you rig something yourself and attempt to seal it tight you'll wind up with condensation on the inside of the container and that will not only ruin your camera but you won't be able to see anything because of the water droplets that you cannot wipe off in a sealed bottle.

Comment: Your response had me thinking about this for quite a bit. I started thinking about moisture and heat concerns. After each remedy that I could think of (e.g. adding a fan and some heating element) the more I realized that an outdoor box would have to provide the same climate that a normal house would - just in miniature. Does this sound about right? Then, maybe, (no kidding) a bird house, with a small computer fan for ventilation. I've not figured out the heating element yet for cold season, but all this could be controlled via some Arduino/RaspPi. Anything is possible, now to find the time.